# Error inflating class (horizontalListView)

Tags: android, listview, layout

I'm trying to use a horizontal view but I get this error:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView

This is the method that gives me the error:

```
public ProfileAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())      //this line exactly
            .inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false);



    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}



XML Layout:

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:widget="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="0dp"
    >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:width="234dp"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
        />



        <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView
            android:id="@+id/active_settings"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ddd"

            />


        <!-- This RelativeLayout makes the button easier to click -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_setting_profile_layout"
            android:layout_width="78dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:clickable="true"
            >



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_setting_profile"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_settings_grey600_24dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your xml card_layout

Comment: ok here it is the xml

Comment: Please verify if DevsmartLib-Android is correctly set into the build path. Clean the application and try rebuilding it. Your xml looks ok to me.

Comment: Now it works. Tha's what I did: nothing. I just cutted a line and copied in the same place

Comment: I am getting the same error.. Any clue on how you resolved?

Answer (score -1):

Check out the card_layout.xml file. May have a syntax error that the IDE is not detecting it. If it seems OK, check out if the library that implements the com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView is included in your project at compile time.